# Make Produce (out) of / from

Tags: grammar, synonyms

> **1a.** He made a little statue (out) of clay.
>   **1b.** He produced a little statue (out) of clay.
>
> **2a.** We can make synthetic fibers from petroleum.
>   **2b.** We can produce synthetic fibers from petroleum.

Are they grammatically correct?

Comment: What is your opinion about the correctness of those sentences? Why do you think they are (not) correct? It is not our habit here to do homeworks or answer quizzes.

Comment: I know “make (out) of” and “make from” is correct. But I doubt  they may be special and other verbs can’t be used in such way.